# Firestore QuerySnapShot is empty on first install or run

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Had a simple query with Firestore inside `ViewModel`, everything is okay except it does not go inside the `for` statement and never triggers and this usually happens on first launch or install of the project.

Note: This is the first page (Fragment) of `ViewPager` while the second page which just have an identical approach on getting documents works fine.

```
fun fetchAssignments(){

        fireStore.collection(appContext.getString(R.string.assignment))
            .whereEqualTo(appContext.getString(R.string.type), GlobalConfig.userData.shift)
            .orderBy(appContext.getString(R.string.time), Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {

                val assList = mutableListOf<AssignmentData>()

                for (item in it){

                    val assignment = item.toObject(AssignmentData::class.java)
                    assignment.documentId = item.id
                    assList.add(assignment)

                }

                assignmentList.value = assList

            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

                assignmentList.value = listOf()

            }

    }
```

But on my second run the `for` statement is working, maybe cache helps as well.

This must be a bug because why such query works on the second fragment with almost same query and not with the first fragment, and why when I call the function again via retry button it works as intended?

For more info check its [ticket](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3203)

Comment: What is 'it' in ```for (item in it){```?

Comment: What type of object is `assignmentList`?

Comment: @AlexMamo its `MutableLiveData<List<AssignmentData>>`

Comment: How to you observe that object?

Comment: just a basic viewmodel observer with viewlifecycle, well Firestore in the first place has empty `QuerySnapshot` so the problem is most likely on that part. Please see the ticket link

Comment: you should follow on the git hub issue to get better resolution on this issue.